# PyDev Generate Properties naming convention

Tags: pydev

From Eclipse, you can click on a Python class variable, and, once it's highlighted, right click to get a context menu, then run "Refactoring->Generate Properties". PyDev will then generate "getters" and "setters" for the member variables you select.

Pydev names the "getter" and "setter" functions "get_" and "set_", lower casing the variable name, and converting camel case names into underscore-separated names. E.g.:

```
class myClass(object):
    myVal = None

    def get_my_val(self):
       return self.__myVal

    def set_my_val(self, value):
       self.__myVal = value

    def del_my_val(self, value):
       del self.__myVal


    myVal = property(get_my_val, set_my_val, del_my_val, "myVal's docstring")
```

I would prefer it make it something more along the lines of setMyVal.

Is there a way to change this naming convention? I saw a different convention used on the [Philip Kershaw blog](http://philipkershaw.blogspot.com/2009/07/pydev-pylint-and-refactoring.html) and so I hope there is a way to do it. I've looked and looked but can't seem to find any reference to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Window`->`Preferences`->`PyDev`->`Editor`->`Code Style` and select both `camelCase with first lower` and `camelCase() with first lower`, then click `Apply`.